# how to create short code for data array sql

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

i'm already can insert data into database using below query. But i want to shortening code for my a few column name because my it just like a continues number. i already explode mark by m1=A, m2=B, m3=C, m4=A and continue..

Below is my controller:

```
$mark = 'ABCADDBBAACBCDDABBCA';
$totalquestion = '10';

for($i=0; $i<$totalquestion; $i++):
  $no = $i+1;
  $m = substr($mark, 0, $no);
endfor;

$data[] = array(
        'TotalQuestion'   => $totalquestion,
        'Mark'   => $mark,
        'm1'    => $m[0],
        'm2'    => $m[1],
        'm3'    => $m[2],
        'm4'    => $m[3],
        'm5'    => $m[4],
        'm6'    => $m[5],
        'm7'    => $m[6],
        'm8'    => $m[7],
        'm9'    => $m[8],
        'm10'    => $m[9],
        'm11'    => $m[10],
        'm12'    => $m[11],
        'm13'    => $m[12],
        'm14'    => $m[13],
        'm15'    => $m[14],
        'm16'    => $m[15],
        'm17'    => $m[16],
        'm18'    => $m[17],
        'm19'    => $m[18],
        'm20'    => $m[19]
        );

$this->excel_import_model->insert($data);
```

This is my result:

[image]

My question is how to re-code for my data[] array so i dont need to type manually m1, m2, m3 till m20. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: just do it once and put it in a function. Then you don't need to type it multiple times but just call the function. Otherwise you can maybe work with a for-loop, because there is always +1 to the next value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $mark = 'ABCADDBBAACBCDDABBCA';
    $totalquestion = '20';

    $data = array();
    $data = array(
        'TotalQuestion'   => $totalquestion,
        'Mark'   => $mark,
     );

    //Split String into array
    $list = str_split($mark);
    $mlist = array();

    //Loop through splited string
    for($i=0; $i<$totalquestion; $i++):
      $mlist['m'.$i] = $list[$i];
    endfor;

    //Merge here or you an even use push array in for loop itslef
    $data = array_merge($data,$mlist);
```

Comment: Great. As i need. Thank you sir